# What does the "#" mean or stand for in a code?

Tags: html

I'm trying to figure out a coding as a newbie. Wondering what the # symbol means or stands for in a code, like `#55555` for a number. Or `#menu1` in a div: `div#menu1 ul.rMenu`?

Trying to back into an education

Answer (score 2):

```
# is used for elements with some id.

<div id="menu"> ====> div#menu

. for class

<div class="menu"> ====> div.menu
```

# refers to hex code

Answer (score 1):

i think in case of  `#55555` , `#` indicates *hexadecimal code* and in case of `#menu1` , `#` indicates `menu1` is an *ID attribute*..

Answer (score 1):

Like many symbols used in programming, the meaning of the symbol is different in different contexts. Below are a few examples:

- #555555 means a colour (grey in this case) in hexadecimal notation.
- #menu1 means any tag with the id "menu1".
- Also other contexts, such as in Cold Fusion #name# means insert the variable named "name".

In general the examples that you're mentioning look like they're from CSS, so feel free to look up CSS:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/

Answer (score 1):

I think people are taking this question a bit too literally and providing answers for those exact two cases.

There is no global convention regarding `#` in source code.  It's a piece of punctuation that doesn't have a conventional use and isn't strongly associated with anything in common use in the English language, so it gets re-used a lot in programming languages.

It's often used to comment out lines (Ruby, Perl, Python, many others):

```
if foo
  # Do something for foo.
end
```

It's used in C and C-derived languages to control the preprocessor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

In addition to the CSS and HTML usages that are already covered.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign#In_computing) for links to many other uses in other programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

```
#55555 - Hexadecimal Number.
#menu1 - id of element
div#menu1 - id of element div.
```

Answer (score 0):

A. Not Code your talking about CSS http://www.html.net/tutorials/css/lesson1.php

B. Your talking about its use in 2 different instances.

1. `#55555` refers to a color. The # before the number says .. Hey I'm going to tell you a colour now
2. `#menu1` refers to a specific ID. 
   This basically means select an element with that id from in a div

For ex.

```
<div>
  <div id="menu1">
          Hi
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS would be something like (Color this red)

```
div #menu1{
     color:#550000; 
}
```